# Mail relay causing AOL bounces

Tags: postfix

I am using postfix to relay both incoming and outgoing emails so I can log them to our CRM. This has been working well for a long time and I have what I feel is a pretty simple process on the server to do this processing. The problem I am experiencing is that message from AOL senders are getting process but rejected by my final IMAP server (gmail) because by server is not allowed to send emails on behalf of aol.com based on their DMARC policy.

Here is the process I have.

When sending out emails, I use my postfix server as my SMTP. So I send an email to sally@aol.com from me@mydomain.com using mypostfix.mydomain.com as the SMTP. Postfix uses 'sender_bcc_maps' for local processing and 'sender_canonical_maps' to alter 'me@mydomain.com' to me@mypostfix.mydomain.com' so replies will come back to this server for processing.

Returned emails thus go to mypostix.mydomain.com and postfix uses recipient_bcc to process locally, and 'recipient_canonical_maps' to change 'me@mypostfix.mydomain.com' to 'me@mydomain.com' and sends the message on. The emails for 'my domain.com' are forwarded to various gmail accounts. Gmail is bouncing those emails.

```
Remote host said: 550-5.7.1 Unauthenticated email from aol.com is not accepted due to domain's
550-5.7.1 DMARC policy. Please contact the administrator of aol.com domain if
550-5.7.1 this was a legitimate mail. Please visit
550-5.7.1  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/2451690 to learn about the
550 5.7.1 DMARC initiative. j15si3385194oih.137 - gsmtp
```

I am pretty sure this is a result of the AOL email being forwarded by my server. Can anyone think of a way to get around this issue and allow these emails to be processed?

Thanks

Comment: Don't forward mail in this manner. If you intend to have Google handle mail for your domain, then do so directly.

Comment: Google does not offer an email solution by which I can pages emails and log them to my CRM. Don't mean to be rude, but just criticizing my process and suggesting using something that would not allow my script processing of emails is not really helpful. Unless I am missing some hidden solution in your reply.

Comment: That's the first you've mentioned anything of _why_ you have this nonstandard setup. The fact remains that your setup as-is **will cause mail to be lost**, not just from AOL but from many providers. So you need to find some other way to do whatever processing you need to do.

Comment: Sorry if you did not understand the first sentence of my initial question, or if it did not describe it in a way that you could understand. And you down-grade my question. Thanks!

Comment: I did not downvote your question. Apparently someone else has a problem with it.

Comment: the answer is coming..... http://arc-spec.org/

Comment: don't post bogus info if you want real help, what is `mydomain`?...gmail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you did not post much info, I can only assume that you are using a domain you own and you are hosted with google apps.

To fix your issue, you must tell google that you explicitly trust this email server (postfix) to send email from anyone, ignoring their email spoofing policies (like SPF or DMARC...no not dkim, dkim just signs the email dmarc is the policy)

Following google's support doc:

> To add IP addresses to your email whitelist:
>
> Sign in to the Google Admin console. From the dashboard, go to Apps >
>   G Suite > Gmail > Advanced settings. In the Organizations section,
>   highlight your domain. In the Email whitelist section, enter the IP
>   addresses of your contact's domain host to make sure any mail
>   originating from these IP addresses are not labeled spam. If you would
>   like to add more than one IP address, enter an IP range in CIDR
>   notation or separate each IP address with a comma. Click Save changes.

https://support.google.com/a/answer/60751?hl=en

Comment: We actually were not using the G Suite, but forwarding from our mail server to individuals' Gmail accounts, but reading your solution help me realize that is probably the way to go. I have set it up now and in process of moving there. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, your problems come from forwarding the mail, but the mail must have been altered in some way (the DKIM signature usually signs only a subset of the headers).

One ugly way would be to rewrite AOL.com in the From: header to something like "AOL.com.invalid" or the like using header_checks:

```
    /^(From:.*)@aol\.com(.*)$/    REPLACE $1@aol.com.invalid$2
```